# Cannot connect to port over the internet (works from localhost)

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, port

I'm running something (=Faye server) on port 9292:

```
david@theta:~$ lsof -ni tcp:9292
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    2406 david   13u  IPv4 1579461398      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9292 (LISTEN)

david@theta:~$ telnet localhost 9292
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

The problem is that from elsewhere I cannot reach it:

```
david@eclipse:~$ telnet 188.226.243.223 9292
Trying 188.226.243.223...
telnet: connect to address 188.226.243.223: Connection refused
```

Port 80 works:

```
david@eclipse:~$ telnet 188.226.243.223 80
Trying 188.226.243.223...
Connected to 188.226.243.223.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I'm not using any firewalls. Is faye bound to 9292 only locally for some reason? Wasn't like that before...

What else can I try?

Thank you,
David

Comment: When you say firewall, are your referring to the firewall on your OS only? Have you verified that the router which supplies an internet connection to that server is allowing connections through that port?

Comment: I'm on Digital Ocean ... are you maybe aware if they block ports like this? I asked on their community forum but no useful answer (only a comment that faye is listening on `localhost`). Should I write to the support? Maybe they did change something in last weeks, it worked before as far as I know.

Comment: I was not aware you are with Digital Ocean, you should definitely contact their support team.

Answer (score 2):

According to your output the application is only listening on lo (127.0.0.1)

This is what you're aiming for

```
david@theta:~$ lsof -ni tcp:9292
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    2406 david   13u  IPv4 1579461398      0t0  TCP *:9292 (LISTEN)
```

You most likely need to amend the configuration of whatever it is you're trying to get working to make it listen on either on all interfaces, or the interface that 188.226.243.223 is bound to.